# email validator in form

Tags: javascript, forms

I,m new in java script.
I have web form and i want to write email validator and cellphone number validator with java script.

I Wrote below script :

```
    function emailValidate(form1, email, cellphone) {
        //debugger;
        var reg = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
        if (reg.test(form1.email.value) == false) {
            alert('آدرس ایمیل وارد شده نامعتبر است');
            return false;
        }

        var x = document.forms["form1"]["cellphone"].value;
        if (! /^[0-9]{11}$/.test(x)) {
            alert("شماره تلفن همراه 11 رقمی وارد کنید.");
            document.getElementById(cellphone).focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and return function in submit of form.function work correctly but after click "ok" button in alert form will submit it means return false in function doesn't work. any body can help me ? thanks

Comment: where exactly are you using this function?

Comment: you might want to look at `[Event.preventDefault();](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)`

Comment: 1. There are top level domains with more than three characters (eg. `.google`), 2. `-` is a valid character in domains. 3. You don't have to have a second level domain (get your own top level domain and allow `name@mytld`).  4. There are are more valid characters in the local part (eg. `'`).

Comment: @OvidiuDolha in form tag

Comment: @Richard thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use validators, you can use HTML5 validator tag which is [pattern](https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_input_pattern.asp). It accepts a RegEx (regular expression).
Here is an example for mail validation:

```
<input type="email" name="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$">
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.how i can change error message in this solution ?

Comment: You can put your warning in the title attribute like this for example: `title="YOUR_WARNING_TEXT"`

Comment: @Mahsa could you please approve the answer if it solves your problem!